# how to calculate percentage of chance in a price negotiation

Tags: probability

I would like to know how to calculate a Percentage of chance in a negotiation.

Here is the problem :

The product has a price of 30€ which represents an acceptance rate of 100%
The minimum price accepted is 27€ which represents an acceptance rate of 50%

How to calculate the acceptance % of the prices between 30 and 27 ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we have to assume a linear relation between price (p) and acceptance rate (a). Next we calculate how much on average the  acceptance loss is if the price is increased by one pound.

The difference between 30 pound and 27 pound is 3 pound. The difference between the corresponding acceptance rates is 50.

Therefore $\frac{50}{3}$ is the loss of the accptance rate per pound. In total the acceptance function is

$a(p)=100-\frac{50}{3}\cdot (30-p)$ for $27\leq p\leq 30$

If $p=29$ the brackets become 1. By adding the brackets we get the price difference.

Comment: Thank you, it works as expected !

Comment: @DanteDiaze You´re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is guessing the function $r(p)$, while knowing $r(27€)=50 \%$ and $r(30€)=100 \%$.
If there is nothing else, the simplest thing to do is to assume a linear law, doing linear interpolation
$$
r(p) = r_1 (1 - \lambda) + r_2 \lambda \\
\lambda = \frac{p - p_1}{p_2 - p1}
$$
**Example:**
$p=28€$, then
$$
r(28€) = 50\% \left( 1 - \frac{28€-27€}{30€-27€}\right) + 100\% \frac{28€-27€}{30€-27€}
= 66.67\%
$$

Comment: Fantastic, would you mind giving me an example with the price 28€ please ? Thank you very much.